# Android Split ABI armeabi-v8a not working. i do not use ndk but have arm binary only work on armeabi-v8a

Tags: android, arm, apk, abi

i have a arm 64bit binary that only work on armeabi-v8a. when i upload to google play other abi users get errors. i do not use ndk
i use this and works perfectly on armeabi-v8a. other people gave me bad reviews because google play showed my app to armeabi-v7a and other abi phones.

```
 Process dd = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(s);
```

i want to know how to filter and give my app only to armeabi-v8a users. so i used abi splits it did not work always showed my app to other abi users. my gradle code is

```
    splits {      
    abi {          
        enable true
        reset()
        include "armeabi-v8a"
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The name of the ABI should be "arm64-v8a", not "armeabi-v8a".